# sending GPS signal by the emulator does not work

Tags: android, eclipse

I have created an App. in a specific activity a GPS signal should received. Since I do not have a real device "Smart Phone", I am using the emulator to test my work.

I tried to send a GPS signal using DDMS perspective "Dalvik Debug Monitor Server" through,"Emulator Control" tab but, nothing appears on the emulator screen.

Please let me know how to solve this.

Comment: Did you allow MOCK LOCATION in your manifest?

Comment: have you enabled GPS in emulator?

Comment: but i have Fine location permission.

Comment: You need the MOCK LOCATION permission too.

Comment: @Ridcully:but it is not listed among the permission group

Comment: You're right. There is a ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION but that's for a different purpose. Have you seen this documentation? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html#MockData

Comment: after adding the required permissions, goto DDMS perspective->emulator control then in"location control" section define a lat and lng values. in case lat and lng are grayed "not active" there should be a sectione titled "Devices" listing many lines. just click one of them and they should be activated.